# How to sort a particular column of prime-ng datatable using custom sorting algorithm

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable, columnsorting

I am working on an older project which uses prime-ng's `p-datatable`. The table currently has default sorting on one column. Now I need to implement sorting on another column but that has to be a custom-logic based sorting.

I tried searching for the ways to do that but found that `p-datatable` provides this feature only on table level and not on column level as shown below:

`<p-dataTable [value]="dataList" (onSort)="sortColumn()>`

Also, I could not find the official documentationpage for `p-datatable`. Apparently it has been deprecated in favour of `Turbotable`.

Can someone please guide me the way of achieving the sorting on new column while keeping the sorting on original column intact.

Edit: If someone has a link to original `p-datatable` documentation, please share the same.

Thanks

Comment: here is link for datatable documentation: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/sort

Comment: Thanks @porgo for the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like

```
<p-column field="abc"  header="ABC" [sortable]="true" sortable="custom" (sortFunction)="buildSort($event)">
```

Your sorting logic will go inside buildSort function. the `event` object will have the details of column and sort value.

Comment: While this might be helpful, it hides the default sorting arrows from the column header. Any idea why ?

Comment: It should not. Please post your code having `p-dataTable` and `p-column` tags.

Comment: It doesn't hide them in single mode, however in multiple mode it does. For now, I can live with that.

Comment: Inside my `buildSort()` function, can I return 1, -1 like we do in regular array sorting or do I need to re-order the entire array ?

Comment: I tried re-ordering the list, but the re-ordered list is not displayed on UI. The view continues to display the original order.

Comment: Are you assigning reordered list to the model which your data table is referring to?

Comment: Yeah. Indeed I am doing so.

Comment: The solution suggested by you works. However, to y surprise it works only on Chrome and not on IE. Did you ever face any such issue ?